# Subdomain forwarding using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, download, subdomain, parallel-processing

I want to redirect a praticular subdomain to the main domain

http(s)://dl.example.com/par1/par2 to http(s)://www.example.com/par1/par2

How to achieve the above using .htaccess

Why i want to do this:
Whenever any user download a file from my server, if the file is huge , then user cannot do any other operation until the file is downloaded completely...so the solution that i have thought is to forward the download request through subdomain so that the browser may continue with rest of the operation.

Thanks

Comment: Well I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Downloading the file and continue surfing on your site shouldn't be affected by this.

Comment: it is .....browser opens only 1 connection at a time for a domain....so when downloading is happening , the browser does not allow any other operation on the same domain.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except from my comment above a Rewrite would like this

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^dl\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$1$       http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Something like this should work, for more info see here
[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: not working for me....
dl.example.com redirects to www.example.com

but dl.example.com/par1/par2 does not redirect..